# Simple goroutine not working on Windows

Tags: windows, go, goroutine

I'm doing some tests with goroutines just to learn how they work, however it seems they are not running at all. I've done a very simple test:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func test() {
    fmt.Println("test")
}

func main() {
    go test()
}
```

I would expect this to print "test" however it simply doesn't do anything, no message but no error either. I've also tried adding a `for {}` at the end of the program to give the goroutine time to print something but that didn't help.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> program execution does not wait for the invoked function to complete
>
> [Go statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements)

Wait a while. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func test() {
    fmt.Println("test")
}

func main() {
    go test()
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
}
```

Output:

```
test
```

Comment: However, as I mentioned in the post, if I add an infinite loop at the end of the program to make it wait, the value is still not printed. Any idea why?

Comment: The infinite loop monopolizes the CPU.

Comment: @Laurent, you should make it clear for yourself that Go's goroutines are not threads, and goroutine is only ever preempted by other goroutines when it is about to sleep in some system (OS) call waiting on some resource (like deta being sent over a network becomes available etc) or when it starts to wait on a Go channel.

Comment: Laurent, try to import runtime and add a `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())` to tell Go to use at least the number of CPUs in your system. As long as it's >1, your go routine should be able to execute, even with an infinite loop (which is a bad idea for other reasons..).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. It's interesting that nearly all the simple examples about goroutines (Tour of Go and the Google blog post I mentioned among others) simply don't work since none of them include a Sleep statement or other ways to give the goroutines time to run.

Comment: If you want a function to block execution, don't put `go` in front if it. Sleep works here, but it's not correct. If you really want this call to be async, you should look into `sync.WaitGroup`  I'm quite certain `for {}` is always the wrong thing to do. Would you do that in C? `select {}` means roughly the same thing as `pause()` in C.

Comment: @Laurent: Take another look at the Go Tour starting at the Concurrency section. Examples surrender control with `runtime.Gosched()', use channels for synchronization, and use 'time', including `time.Sleep()` for synchronization.

Comment: @Dustin, `for {}` is something I would avoid in any language but I wanted to test quickly and I (wrongly) assumed that the goroutines would still run. I've ended up using `sync.WaitGroup` in my program, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 10):

I know it's answered, but for the sake of completeness:

**Channels**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func test(c chan int) {
    fmt.Println("test")

    // We are done here.
    c <- 1
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go test(c)

    // Wait for signal on channel c
    <- c
}
```

Comment: Source: [http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels)